# What is the formula behind adjusted R^2 for generalized additive model in mgcv package?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

After fitting generalized additive models using the R package `mgcv`, from the summary, I can find `R^2(adjusted)`. I want to know how it is actually calculated? I mean what is its formula?
Code:

```
library(mgcv)
x=runif(100)
x2=runif(100)
y=sin(x)+exp(x2) + rnorm(0,1)
m=gam(y~s(x,bs="cr",k=4)+s(x2,bs="cr",k=4),method="REML")
summary(m)
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400933/which-index-is-preferred-in-gam-r-sq-or-deviance-explained ?

Answer (score 3):

> i try to look at the source code of mgcv but i am unable to find out
> r2

If you look at the source code of `print.summary.gam`, you see this:

```
if (!is.null(x$r.sq)) 
        cat("R-sq.(adj) = ", formatC(x$r.sq, digits = 3, width = 5), 
            "  ")
```

If you look at the source code of `summary.gam`, you see this:

```
residual.df <- length(object$y) - sum(object$edf)

w <- as.numeric(object$prior.weights)

mean.y <- sum(w * object$y)/sum(w)

nobs <- nrow(object$model)

r.sq <- if (inherits(object$family, "general.family") || 
        !is.null(object$family$no.r.sq)) 
        NULL
    else 1 - var(w * (as.numeric(object$y) - object$fitted.values)) * 
        (nobs - 1)/(var(w * (as.numeric(object$y) - mean.y)) * 
        residual.df)
```